# Play sound on internal speakers and possibility to use old xp api function?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, windows-7, beep

After the release of windows vista the Windows Function [Beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) plays a beep on your connected speakers instead of the internal one.

Is there anyway to access the old function? Would it be possible by getting hold in an older windows api? Or is there any other way i can make this possible? If so i would like the ability to set both the frequency and duration.

I should mention that I´m actually targeting the windows xp platform.

Comment: For what it's worth, this functionality was probably removed because a lot of newer computers either don't have a system speaker, or only have it implemented via the sound card. If you want to play tones, use a real audio API. :)

Comment: I recently bought a new and fresh motherboard (MSI-Z68A) and it came with an internal speaker. Most computers still have internal speakers and use them to alert during POST (power-on self-test).

Comment: ...but lots of computers *don't*. The ones you assemble yourself from pieces often do, because these are targeted at enthusiasts who care about things like POST and overclocking, but OEMs have stopped including hardware speakers for cost reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The function is implemented in a Kernel32.dll, which is loaded at runtime from whatever version of the OS you're currently running.  Since the code isn't there in either your executable or in a system DLL, you can't run it (don't even think about copying over Kernel32.dll from a different OS version, that's just screaming for trouble).

You can try using [`MessageBeep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `Beep`, but that gives you less control over the output and will probably still use your sound card instead of the internal

For an interesting history of the `MessageBeep` function, see [Larry Osterman's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx).

Comment: Would running it in a virtual machine with XP produce beeps on the internal speaker?

Comment: @DavidJensen: No, that is unlikely.

Comment: @DavidJensen: Unlikely but possible, depending on the VM implementation.  It depends on whether the VM's implementation of the 8254 drivers passes it through to the real machine's 8254 or to its sound card.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of computers now don't have internal speakers, so there's nothing there to access.

The function was intentionally removed in Windows 7, according to [Larry Osterman's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/); [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx) from the archives specifically discusses that issue. It seems that `Beep.sys` was removed, and the functionality of that old pseudo-device driver was changed to intentionally redirect sound to the sound card instead. The article is an interesting read from a historical standpoint.

Larry is a MS employee who worked on the new audio framework for Vista and Win7, and he's been at MS since the dinosaur days (MS-DOS at least :D) so he'd probably know. :)