# Make beep sound in BIOS

Tags: c++, assembly, interrupt, bios

When computer starts to boot, It makes a beep sound **from the BIOS Speaker**.

How do i can do this in Assembly or C++ ? 
Clearly I want to make Beep Sound by BIOS Speaker.

**Remember i mean BIOS Speakers**

Does it have any interrupt for that ? I searched about that but nothing found..
I used some interrupt But the didn't do this. the following code :

```
int main(){
   cout<<"\a";
}
```

Produced the sound from the Speaker, Not Bios

How can i do this ? with any interrupt ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10216931/3191896

Comment: Any other way ? In assembly ?

Comment: AFAIK, Windows removed support for the built-in speaker in Windows 7.

Comment: @immibis : can i write a driver for that ? :)

Comment: @Alireza378nA If you want to write a driver.... which you probably don't.

Comment: @immibis : surely it can be done with VBE (VESA BIOS Extensions) but there is should be another way it think....

Comment: With output the bell ASCII(7)?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this code, too.

```
.pause1:
    mov     cx, 65535
.pause2:
    dec     cx
    jne     .pause2
    dec     bx
    jne     .pause1
    in      al, 61h         ; Turn off note (get value from
                            ;  port 61h).
    and     al, 11111100b   ; Reset bits 1 and 0.
    out     61h, al         ; Send new value.
```

So, the result is:

```
void beep(){

    __asm{

      MOV al, 182         ; Prepare the speaker for the
      out     43h, al     ;  note.
      mov     ax, 2280    ; Frequency number (in decimal)
                          ;  for C.
      out     42h, al     ; Output low byte.
      mov     al, ah      ; Output high byte.
      out     42h, al 
      in      al, 61h     ; Turn on note (get value from
                          ;  port 61h).
      or      al, 00000011b   ; Set bits 1 and 0.
      out     61h, al         ; Send new value.
      mov     bx, 4       ; Pause for duration of note.


    .pause1:
       mov     cx, 65535
    .pause2:
       dec     cx
       jne     .pause2
       dec     bx
       jne     .pause1
       in      al, 61h         ; Turn off note (get value from
                               ;  port 61h).
       and     al, 11111100b   ; Reset bits 1 and 0.
       out     61h, al         ; Send new value.

   };
}
```

Comment: `in` and `out` are privileged instructions; you can't use them in user-space under most OSes.  (Under Linux, there's `ioperm` and `iopl` system calls to let a process request IO privilege, but that could interfere with a kernel driver using the PC speaker).  This code might work in a DOS program with an ancient 16-bit C++ compiler, though.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can implement this in any modern Windows OS is, I guess, writing Kernel Mode driver. The reason is that `in` or `out` instructions are not available in user mode, and there is no API for beeper available.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554836(v=vs.85).aspx

However, if you're just willing to dig into low-level programming, consider writing own bootloader or even own BIOS (using virtual machine).

Answer (score -1):

Try to include this procedure in your C++ program.

```
void beep(){

    __asm{

      MOV al, 182         ; Prepare the speaker for the
      out     43h, al     ;  note.
      mov     ax, 2280    ; Frequency number (in decimal)
                          ;  for C.
      out     42h, al     ; Output low byte.
      mov     al, ah      ; Output high byte.
      out     42h, al 
      in      al, 61h     ; Turn on note (get value from
                          ;  port 61h).
      or      al, 00000011b   ; Set bits 1 and 0.
      out     61h, al         ; Send new value.
      mov     bx, 4       ; Pause for duration of note.
   };
}
```

Comment: `in` and `out` are privileged instructions. They won't work in an user mode application.

Comment: Probably, your beep cames out from PC speakers or earphones; Not from PC BIOS Speaker. So are you sure that your device don't produce any sound?

Comment: Don't post multiple versions of the same answer; in future edit a single answer.  Since you already have one answer with your full code, you should delete this one.